# Looping through query results does not work. No error

Tags: laravel-4, query-builder

I cannot figure it out. Beyond my comprehension.

I have a user class I have been working that extends my base class which extends Eloquent.
I run the following query to get results

```
$sql = 'Email = \''.$email_to_check.'\'';
$results = $this->whereRaw($sql);
```

I then attempt to run the following

```
if($results->count( ) > 0){
        $all_pass = true;           
        foreach ($results as $user){
            die('magic');
            if(!$user->sendEmailValidationEmail( )){
                $all_pass = false;
            }
        }
        die('Failed');
}
```

Now by this rational I should either see the output of nothing or 'magic'.
However 'Failed' is returned.

I have no idea why.
I can check the counts all day long and they are all fine.
All the docs say this is the way to loop through results.
What is going on???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think whereRaw() might still return a Query Builder instance which count() will still work on.

Can you try updating your code to:

```
foreach ($results->get() as $user){
```

And see how you get on with that.